# LINQ Sub-select from Dictionary based on value type

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to sub-select a `Dictionary<String, Double>` from a `Dictionary<String, String>`. To do this, I use a `IEnumrable<>.Where` so sub-select a `Dictionary<String, String>` (which works), then cast it to `Dictionary<String, Double>` (doesn't work).

**My Code:**

```
//linesTable is an System.data.DataTable object
//...for loop code in here
DataRow row = linesTable.Rows[i]; //Where i is the loop index
Dictionary<String, String> valuesDictionary 
    = row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(
                col => col.ColumnName, 
                col => row.Field<String>(col.ColumnName));
//ATTEMPT #1
/*Dictionary<String, Double> numericValues = valuesDictionary.Where(
                subs => 
                    { 
                        double doubleValue; 
                        return double.TryParse(subs.Value, out doubleValue);                
                    }).Cast<Dictionary<String, Double>>();*/
//ATTEMPT #2
Dictionary<String, Double> numericValues = valuesDictionary.Where(
    subs => {
        double doubleValue;
        return double.TryParse(subs.Value, out doubleValue);
    }
).ToDictionary<String, Double>(
    pair => pair.Key,
    pair => double.Parse(pair.Value));
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

The reason I need it in a `Dictionary<String, Double>` format is because I have a method that takes in this type that I need to pass the dictionary data to.

*Thanks in advance!*

> **SIMILAR QUESTIONS:** My question is similar to these: http://bit.ly/12qjrmE, http://bit.ly/YmuRHZ and
>   http://bit.ly/XLQNaB, except that I want the subquery to return a
>   Dictionary type as well.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks heaps for your solutions. They're in a similar vain. I tried it: `Dictionary<String, Double> numericValues = valuesDictionary.Where( subs => { double doubleValue; return double.TryParse(subs.Value, out doubleValue); }).ToDictionary<String, Double>(pair => pair.Key, pair => double.Parse(pair.Value));`

Comment: ...got the following error:
_'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToDictionary<TSource,TKey>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TKey>)' has some invalid arguments_

Comment: Is that because the `.Where` returns a `KeyValuepair<>`?

Comment: It's not LINQ2SQL. Funny, it should work!

Comment: According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx, Dictionary<> implements IEnumrable<KeyValuepair<>>, so creating a dictionary from it should work.

Comment: I'm just confused because it seems to indicate you are doing a parallel query.

Comment: Not sure, I am not very familiar with LINQ. I just started using it this week, so, I don't even know what a parallel query is. I am investigating LINQ to try and understand what the extension methods do.

Comment: Can you update your code with the exact code you used to try our solutions, including (if possible) how `row` gets its value?

Comment: Code has been updated @JamesMichaelHare

Comment: @Constantine's has worked, so I am taking it as the accepted answer. I learned a lot from James' answer as well. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need `Dictionary<String, String>`, you could make it at once:

```
Dictionary<String, Double> valuesDictionary =
    row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                     .Where(col =>
                     {
                         double d;
                         return double.TryParse(row.Field<String>(col.ColumnName), out d);
                     })
                     .ToDictionary(
                         col => col.ColumnName,
                         col => double.Parse(row.Field<String>(col.ColumnName)));
```

Comment: This compiled for me, so I will give it a go.

Another alternative to `col => double.Parse(row.Field<String>(col.ColumnName)))` is `col => (row.Field<Double>(col.ColumnName))`

Comment: @Sinker Then it's even much better, to use `row.Field<Double>(col.ColumnName)` in `ToDictionary`:):)

Comment: Despite compiling correctly, it failed to execute properly. I reverted back to `double.Parse(row.Field<String>(col.ColumnName)))` which was the condition in the `.Where` method call anyway.

Comment: @Sinker probably `row.Field<Double>` expected a field of type `double` and did not intend to do type cast on its own.

Answer (score 4):

You can't *cast* a `Dictionary<string, string>` to a `Dictionary<string, double>` because it isn't one.  You would need to create a new `Dictionary` instead (or go straight to the `Dictionary<string,double>` if you don't need the `Dictionary<string,string>` as Konstantin suggests).

In fact, your code doesn't even really do what you're thinking.  The `Cast<Dictionary<string,Double>>()` that you chained onto the `Where()` is attempting to cast every item in the `IEnumerable` to the `Dictionary<string, Double>`.

I think what you want instead is:

```
Dictionary<String, Double> numericValues = valuesDictionary
      .Where(
            pair => 
                { 
                    double doubleValue; 
                    return double.TryParse(subs.Value, out doubleValue);                
                })
      .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => double.Parse(pair.Value);
```

That is, for all cases where the `double` can be parsed, put them in a new `Dictionary<string, double>`.

Of course, you could use a RegEx, or something similar to make the `Where` prettier, but the essential point is that `Cast<>()` is to cast each *item* in the sequence, it doesn't cast the sequence as a whole.  Further, you *can't* cast the sequence as a whole, because a `Dictionary<string,string>` is *not* a `Dictionary<string,double>`.

Thus, you need a new `Dictionary`, and using `ToDictionary()` is one option to get there...